# Combinatorics - Probability

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are playing a game with $2$ standard dice. Both the dice are rolled together and the total is counted. $A$ says that a total of $2$ will be rolled first. $B$, whereas, says that two Consecutive totals of $7$ will be rolled first. They keep rolling the dice till one of them wins! What is the probability that $A$ wins the game?

Why is the method ($$\frac{1}{36} + \frac{35}{36}*\frac{1}{36} + \frac{35}{36}*\frac{29}{36}*\frac{1}{36} + \frac{35}{36}*\frac{29}{36}*\frac{29}{36}*\frac{1}{36}+ \cdots$$) wrong?

Comment: Your title and question do not match.

Comment: Explain your thought process as to how you came up with that "method".

Comment: (1/36 = Probability that sum is 2)
(35/36*1/36 = Probability that sum in first roll is any number from 3 to 12 and sum in second roll is 2)

(35/36*29/36*1/36 = Probability that sum in first roll is any number from 3 to 12, sum in second roll is neither 2 nor 7,  sum in second roll is 2)

.

.

.

.

 and so on

Comment: @Anisha Jain, you should edit that into your question.  You will be more likely to get an answer that way.  The title is now a bit too vague.

Comment: The problem with your series is that by using  powers of 29/36 in every term after the first two, you are assuming that there are intermediate 7's every time, which there won't be. For example, your series doesn't count the game that goes 4, 8, 9, 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the prob. that A wins.

Then using recursion when a non-2 or non-7 is rolled, we have

$p=1/36 + 6/36(1/36) + (29/36)p + (1/6)(29/36)p$ and solving gives $p=7/13$.

RHS: (prob 2 on roll 1) + prob (7 then 2) + prob(non-2,7)*p + prob(7 then non-2,7)*p

The idea is that after a non-2,7 the game is starting over with prob $p$ of A winning from that point.

Comment: And if you want to do it as a geometric series, the first term is 7/216  and the common ratio is (7*29/216), which you can see by reverse engineering the recursive equation. Deriving the geometric series directly is trickier, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are just two nonterminal states of the game, namely $S_1$: there is no $7$ from the previous throw, and $S_2$: immediately before a $7$ was thrown. Denote by $p_i$  the probability that A wins when we are in state $S_i$. Then
$$p_1={1\over36}+{29\over36}p_1+{1\over6}p_2,\qquad p_2={1\over36}+{29\over36}p_1\ .$$
Solving this system gives $p_1={\displaystyle{7\over13}}$.